# Render a Wordpress page as a variable

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to get Wordpress to render a page and return it as HTML ?

I'm thinking about a function that'd look like this :

```
$html = render_page($id);
echo $html; // prints the page
```

My goal is to have all my sections' HTML and my corresponding logic in different files and, in my home page file, merge all the different sections in the order I wish. Thus making a one-page kind of website.

Because you define a template for a page, I don't see why it's doesn't seem to be possible to do this.

Comment: Let me see if I understood you correctly.
You want to convert your html page straight to a wordpress format (as a template)?

Comment: Not really @HashiramaSenju, I have sections of my home page (only page of the site) defined in different template files in my theme. What I want to do is render them on one single page. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Have a look at `get_template_part()`

Comment: This is good for getting a static bit of HTML, but `get_template_part()` doesn't seem to actually evaluate the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a workaround for doing exactly what I wanted :

- I have all my different "pages" (they are Wordpress pages, but I use them as different sections on a one-page site) in different files.
- Each file has it's own HTML and corresponding logic.
- In my `index.php` file, I call my files this way :

> `require_once(locate_template('tpl-name.php'));`

I'm pretty sure it's not exactly the best way of doing it, but it works for me. Wish Wordpress would allow API access to it's rendering though.